# PHP Upload and overwrite photo file

Tags: php, file, upload, photo, overwrite

I'm working with some pretty plain PHP.

User upload of photo files with some destination and same name, so that the newest upload will overwrite older versions.

Right now my code seems to work. I get the upload comment I should, but no files in destination folder.
Ive been searching stackoverflow, but I just cant seem to figure it out.

**HTML:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = 'profilepicture/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    echo "<p>";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_FILES) ?

Comment: Do you see any errors? (you may want to switch on `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL)`. Can you post the result of `print_r($_FILES)` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you're checking the `profilepicture` folder relative to your PHP file? Keep in mind that any user would be able to upload "another" users filename and therefore replace their picture. Maybe append the userID (if they're logged in).

Comment: Thanks for inputs.
Darhazer and Edga, i get this from the error reporting:
File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.

"Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => navigation.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /var/tmp/phpbfXB6s
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 10787
        )

)

Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => navigation.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /var/tmp/phpbfXB6s [error] => 0 [size] => 10787 ) )"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE` has been set to somewhat bigger than 2BM (default seetings in php.ini). To my experience, I set it to 20MB so for image that is bigger than 2BM will also be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

what's platform that you work with ? if it's unix, check "profilepicture" permission and right relative path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer redwind - how do i check the permission?